# When to use the user Java keyword Throw on a user-defined Exception?

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a user-defined exception and only catch it in a try-catch or does the user-defined exception have to be thrown with the throw statement.

Question: I am somewhat confused on whether when to use the throw keyword? I think that the throw is used with user-defined Exceptions.

Code: (Java)

```
public genericPanel() {
  try {
    if (i.length == size) {
      throw new MyOwnDefinedError("Error - Size is 1 integer
                                                              to large");
     }
     for (int index=0;index<=i.length;index++) {
        System.out.println(i[index]);
     }
  } catch (MyOwnDefinedError o) {
       o.getMessage();
  } catch (Exception e) {
       e.getMessage();
  }
}

class MyOwnDefinedError extends Exception {
  MyOwnDefinedError(String myNewString) {
    super( myNewString);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You use `throw` when you want to break the program flow and throw an exception.

Comment: Is your question more about how to use the `catch` keyword to catch your own exceptions? Exceptions can be generated by the Java Runtime,  `throw`n by code that you call, or you can `throw` an instance of an exception yourself (which can be an exception you defined or a pre-defined one). With that info, can you clarify what you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

`throw` is used whenever you want to throw any `Exception`, whether user-defined or not. There is no difference between "pre-defined" exceptions (like `IOException`) or self-defined one, as in your `MyOwnDefinedError`.

Answer (score 0):

The `throw` keyword in java is used for user defined exceptions you are right. For example you are doing a banking application and you want to withdraw money from a customer's account. As is normal, the amount cannot go negative so you would throw a `InvalidAmountException` or something similar.

The keyword itself is used every time when an exceptional situation needs to be underlined, hence you will use throw for throwing any kind of exception, that exists in the API already or one that an user implemented.

As it goes for the handling of the exception - if one extends the Exception class from java, the Exception should be specifically placed on the method definition by using the `throws` keyword. If you want the exception to pop-up at runtime and maybe interrupt the execution of your program you can extend the RuntimeException. In this case, the exception handling it is optional - you don't have to specify it with throws or you don't have to wrap the execution of the method with try/catch block.

A complete tutorial on exception can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the answer in the java documentation on throwing excepions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

> Before you can catch an exception, some code somewhere must throw one.
>   Any code can throw an exception: your code, code from a package
>   written by someone else such as the packages that come with the Java
>   platform, or the Java runtime environment. Regardless of what throws
>   the exception, it's always thrown with the throw statement.
>
> As you have probably noticed, the Java platform provides numerous
>   exception classes. All the classes are descendants of the Throwable
>   class, and all allow programs to differentiate among the various types
>   of exceptions that can occur during the execution of a program.
>
> You can also create your own exception classes to represent problems
>   that can occur within the classes you write. In fact, if you are a
>   package developer, you might have to create your own set of exception
>   classes to allow users to differentiate an error that can occur in
>   your package from errors that occur in the Java platform or other
>   packages

Answer (score 0):

- Throw is used to throw an exception.
- Throw is a part of method definition.
- At a given point of time, a throw statement can only throw one exception.
- A throw statement is post fixed by an instance of exception.

Comment: Can you show an example of the method definition. For example if I have my own exception that extends exception like above. When I use the throws in the method stub then the class that creates and instance of that class has an unhandled exception error.

Answer (score 0):

class Test
{

```
void testDivision(float a,float b)
{
if(b=0.0)
 {
  try
  {
    throw new MathematicalException("Please, do not divide by zero");
  }
    catch (MathematicalException ae)
        {
        System.out.println(ae);
        }
 }
else
    {
    float result=a/b;
            System.out.println("Result:" + result);
    }       
}

public static void main(String args[])

{
float f1 = Float.parsefloat(args[0]);
float f2 = Float.parsefloat(args[1]);

Test t1 = new Test();
t1.testDivision(f1,f2);
}

class MathematicalException extends Exception

            {
                MathematicalException();



                MathematicalException(String msg)
    {
    super(msg);
    }
            }
```

}